# Matching multiple column criteria in an R dataframe from integer vectors

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataframe, populated with 1's and 0's.
I have two integer vectors, "a" and "b" which relate to specific columns in the dataframe. No column reference in a exists in b, and vice versa (i.e. no intersect).

What I'm trying to do is generate a new column containing a flag when: 
 ANY of the columns in "a" are 1 (on a given row) and
 ALL of the columns in "b" are 0 (on the same row)

I'm trying to do this by:

```
processed.tbl$flag <- ifelse(processed.tbl[, a] == 1 & processed.tbl[, b] ==0,
                             1, 0)
```

but I get an error of non-conformable arrays, presumably because it's trying to join the two table subsets. How do I do this correctly (in base R ideally)?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you are probably looking for nested `ifelse`...

Comment: you could just sum if sum = 0 it's good return 1 if it's >0 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay; think I've found a way to do this, but please do add if there's a slicker way!

```
processed.tbl$flag[
        which(  apply(processed.tbl[, b], MARGIN = 1, function(x) all (x == 0))
               &apply(processed.tbl[, a], MARGIN = 1, function(y) any (y == 1))
                , arr.ind = FALSE)] <- 1
```